Build a OSM map on Flutter Project

error: The named parameter 'trackMyPosition' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [final2] lib\Components\MapScreen.dart:38)

List item

trackMyPosition.
initZoom.
minZoomLevel.
maxZoomLevel.
stepZoom.
userLocationMarker.
roadConfiguration.
markerOption.

I use this dependencies:
 flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_core: ^3.1.0
  animate_do: ^3.3.4
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^7.0.0
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.3.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  flutter_map: ^7.0.1
  latlong2: ^0.9.1
  geolocator: ^12.0.0
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  google_ml_vision: ^0.0.8
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  timezone: ^0.9.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.3
  intl: ^0.19.0
  flutter_osm_plugin: ^0.70.4

Here is the code:
import 'package:flutter_osm_plugin/flutter_osm_plugin.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MapScreen({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  late MapController _mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mapController = MapController(
      initMapWithUserPosition: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _mapController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: OSMFlutter(
        controller: _mapController,
        trackMyPosition: true,
        initZoom: 12,
        minZoomLevel: 8,
        maxZoomLevel: 18,
        stepZoom: 1.0,
        userLocationMarker: UserLocationMaker(
          personMarker: MarkerIcon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.location_history_rounded,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 48,
            ),
          ),
          directionArrowMarker: MarkerIcon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.double_arrow,
              size: 48,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        roadConfiguration: RoadConfiguration(
          startIcon: MarkerIcon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: 64,
              color: Colors.brown,
            ),
          ),
          roadColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        ),
        markerOption: MarkerOption(
          defaultMarker: MarkerIcon(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person_pin_circle,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 56,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        osmOption: OSMOption(
          showZoomController: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

** Who can I ask to solve the problem? **


The OSMFlutter widget does not have a parameter named trackMyPosition.
As per the official example trackMyPosition is a parameter of OSMOption, not OSMFlutter. You need to pass that to the osmOption parameter of OSMFlutter widget.
Your zoom settings should also be passed in via ZoomOption.
OSMFlutter( 
  controller: _mapController,
  osmOption: OSMOption(
    trackMyPosition: true,
    showZoomController: true,
  ),
  zoomOption: ZoomOption(
    initZoom: 12,
    minZoomLevel: 8,
    maxZoomLevel: 18,
    stepZoom: 1.0,
  ),
  ...etc...
);

